# Does the verb 'choose' call for the same constructions as 'buy''?

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1.1 He bought me a new coat. 
>   1.2 He bought a new coat for me.
>
> 2.1 He chose me the coat.
>   2.2 He chose the coat for me.

Both 1.1 and 1.2 are from [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/buy_1), while 2.1 and 2.2 are mine. Can the latter be made and used as the same pattern as the former?

Comment: 2.1 is just wrong. 2.2 is correct, though haven't heard someone choosing a **coast** for somebody!! ;)

Comment: Is there some reason you think the construction is the same? Adding such information would be helpful. Otherwise you might just get "no".

Comment: Aside: I'd use *call for* rather than *select* in your title, as *select* is a little too active / requires a bit too much agency for use with an inanimate subject, whereas *call for* can be used in the sense of *cause to be necessary; require*.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Thank you for your comment. I changed the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your sentences are acceptable. However, they are likely to appear in slightly different contexts. Note that with the definite article, *the coat*, the coat must already have been mentioned or must be defined immediately.

> *He chose me the coat* is unlikely to appear except with an adjunct specifying *which* coat he chose: *He chose me the coat with the fur collar*, *He chose me the new coat he had promised.*
>
> *He chose the coat for me* will usually appear with an emphasis somewhere in the preposition phrase, either on *for* (signifying that he chose the coat because I was unwilling or unable to choose for myself) or or *me* (signifying that the coat was intended for me rather than someone else).

Designating the beneficiary of an action (Indirect Object) with a noun or bare object pronoun before the Direct Object is quite common in casual speech; it is not restricted to those verbs which dictionaries recognize as ‘ditransitive’.

> The band played **John** his favorite song.
> If you'll open **me** this jar of pickled beets I'll fix **you** a salad.
> IT installed **us** a new app to handle versioning.

The construction is not so common in formal texts, but it is acceptable:

> In 1528 [Henry VIII] owned a carcanet with H and K, for himself and Katharine of Aragon, and later Holbein designed **him** a pendant with H and I for himself and Jane Seymour.  —Joan Evans, *A History of Jewelry, 1100-1870*, 1970.

Comment: One query, sir. If I say this to my daughter... *I have bought you a doll* and *I have bought a doll for you* -they seem to be different. In former case, my daughter *has seen* the doll because I *took* her to the shop and got her the doll, but in the latter case, *she's just informed* and has not yet seen the doll. Suppose it's her birthday and she asks me on the phone that what did I buy for her? I answer, *I have bought a doll for you*. I don't think *I've bought you a doll* works there. What say?

Comment: @MaulikV I think they're both equivalent there. Keep in mind that the 'dative alternation' (S-V-IO-DO > S-VO-DO-to/for-IO) exists primarily to permit a) focusing on IO rather than DO and b) moving a 'heavy' IO to the end, for easier parsing.

Comment: @StoneyB, What a glee! I regarded 2.1 as an unused construction and forgot about it. Were not your reply, I would have been keeping my ignorance. Thank you so much.

Comment: I knew that's your brainchild and I just stole it from you. Again, the dictionaries don't classify 'choose' as a ditransitive verb. I therefore consider 2.1 as an example in which the 'heavy' IO is put to the end. You've made me think in your way. :-) @StoneyB